# Python OpenCV images get blurry after successive shots

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to Open CV and python, and I've been facing a problem:

I've been doing a project on my Raspberry Pi where the webcam takes a grey scale image, removes the background, and saves it in a folder.

This is used by a machine learning algorithm to detect the object in the image.

The webcam is fixed at a particular point so I first take an image of the background and then take a picture of the object. The background is then removed from the object and it looks fine.

But if I repeat the process and overwrite the image, it becomes blurred.

This effect keeps happening until after about three or four shots the image becomes blurry and my program cant identify the object in it.

My code is:

```py
#get Background
import cv2
cam = cv2.videoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cam.read()
if ret:
    img_name = '/home/pi/Desktop/background.png'
    grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, grey_img)
    print('{} written'.format(img_name))
cam.release()
```

```py
#takeImage
import cv2
import numpy as np
ret, frame = cam.read()
back = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/background.png')
if ret:
    img_name = '/home/pi/Desktop/img_capture.png'
    grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, grey_img)
    grey_obj = cv2.subtract(cv2.imread(img_name), back)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, grey_obj)
    print('{} written'.format(img_name))
cam.release()
```

I'm using a Logitech webcam but I'm not sure of the exact model

Please help me out, and thanks in advance.

Clear at the start:
[image]

Not so much:
[image]

Not at all:
[image]

Comment: You're saving both the background and the new image with the same file name.

Comment: @101..mistake in the code. edited that.

Comment: Why do you keep writing the image to file and  then reading it back again? That is highly redundant! Are you sure it is not the camera itself that goes out of focus?

Comment: It's not getting blurry, it's getting lighter. Either you are adding subsequent frames up, or your camera's exposure time increases.

Comment: This could very well be caused by overwriting the background image. Is that typo in your original post also in the code that produced these images?

Comment: @Cris Luengo no, it was only in the question. my actual code doesn't do that.

Comment: have you ever solved this?